# Forcing a function to restore all registers before making a function call

Tags: c, assembly, operating-system, embedded

I am using an EK-LM4F120XL board, which contains a cortex-M4 processor. I also use GCC-ARM-none-eabi as toolchain.

I am building on a little hobby project, which slowly becomes an operating system. An important part of this is that I need to switch out registers to switch processes. This happens inside an interrupt and this specific processor makes sure that all the temporary registers (r0-r3, r12, lr) are pushed to the process stack. So in order to continue I need to write the content of r4-r11 and the SP to a place in memory, I need to load the r4-r11 of the new process, load its stackpointer and return. Additionally the lr value contains some information about the process that was interrupted, so I need information from that register too.

All of this works, because I wrote it in assembly. I linked the assembly function directly to the interrupt, so I have full control over what happens to the registers. The combination of C and inline assembly did not work because the compiler usually pushes some registers to the stack and that is fatal. But the OS is growing and the context change is growing along: there are now also some global variables that need changing, etc. All of this is doable in assembly, but its becoming a pain: assembly is hard to read and to debug. So I want a C/Assemlby combo. Basically I am looking for something like this:

```
void contextSwitch(void){
    //Figure out what the next process will be
    //Change every variable that needs changing

    // Restore register state to the moment of interrupt. The following function will not return in the sense that it will end the interrupt.
    swapRegisters(oldProc, newProc);
}
```

And then write only swapRegisters in assembly. Is there a way to achieve this? Is my solution even the best solution?

Comment: You are writing an OS kernel.  It's really hard, especially interrupt drivers.  I'm not sure what anyone could do over a blog, or even what your exact problem is.

Comment: Do you mean my question is unclear?

Comment: Your kernel entry can save all the registers into memory, so the C side only has to manipulate memory. The exit then restores it. The entry/exit is in assembly.

Comment: That might actually be the best solution! Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

There is no portable method of directly accessing CPU registers in C; you will need assembler, in-line assembler, compiler intrinsics or a kernel library (that uses assembler code).

The details of how that is done for Cortex-M are well covered elsewhere and probably too complex to be repeated here: The specifics of doing this in Cortex-M4(F) are described at the ARM Info Center site [here](http://infocenter.arm.com/help/index.jsp?topic=/com.arm.doc.dai0298a/index.html).  The approach is broadly similar for the Cortex-M3 except for the FPU considerations, an M3 specific description of context switching is provided [in this Embedded.com article](http://www.embedded.com/design/prototyping-and-development/4231326/Taking-advantage-of-the-Cortex-M3-s-pre-emptive-context-switches).

As you can never have enough explanations because different authors make some things clearer than others or give better or more directly applicable examples, [here's another](http://www.thewireframecommunity.com/writing-a-basic-multitasking-os-for-arm-cortex-m3-processor) - also M3 based, but will work on M4 if not using the FPU or for M4's without an FPU.  And [yet another example](http://mmcircuit.com/implement-rtos-on-cortex-m3-microcontroller/).

Comment: When I started working on the context switcher I read trough these sources. One big disadvantage of them is that none of them make guarantees about which registers are pushed to the stack and editted by the C function before the inline assembly comes into play. The GCC compiler turned out to push important registers to the stack almost always before the inline assembly was hit, and thus I decided to do the entire thing in assembly. These resources do not help for my problem.

Comment: @Cheiron : The function that restores the context does not return; the switching of the stack-pointer, poping of registers and final `bx lr` cause a return directly to the target context (because the link-register `LR` is modified by the pop, and the `bx lr` modifies the PC), so the registers are not modified by the switching function exit epilogue because it does not exit - it remains unreachable code.